# Is there a simpler way of writing this sorting code?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have a list of 196 strings in the form **2009/EPS.WCR.PL6.MAIS.0036, 2016/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0077** etc. What varies is the year date and the four numbers at the end. Also there are either NORM or MAIZE. I would like to go through this list and extract these bits of information to create a some sort of distance matrix. The code I have written so far is as follow:
`c(substr(df[i,3], 1, 4),substr(df[1,3], 18, 21),substr(df[i,3], 22, nchar(df[i,4]))),`
 where df is the list of these catagorical variables.

Where i loops through the list. Is there a nice way of getting a distance between these strings based on the bits of information that I am extracting?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of distance? Are you using a package such as `stringdist` to compute the distances? And do you want, say, the distance between `20090036` and `20160077` or what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you data has the same structure throughout then try:

```
    data <- c("2009/EPS.WCR.PL6.MAIS.0036", "2016/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0077")
    str(data)
    substr(data, start = 1, stop = 4)
    substr(data, start = 18, stop = 21)
    substr(data, start = 23, stop = 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function uses CRAN package [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html) to compute the distances between the strings in its first argument. You can pass a `method` of your choice, see the help page `help("stringdist")`.

```
special_dist <- function(x, method = "osa"){
  y <- sub("(^[[:digit:]]+).*[[:punct:]]([[:digit:]]+$)", "\\1\\2", x)
  res <- sapply(y, function(z) stringdist::stringdist(z, y, method = method))
  rownames(res) <- colnames(res)
  res
}

x <- c("2009/EPS.WCR.PL6.MAIS.0036", "2016/EPS.WCR.PL6.NORM.0077")
special_dist(x)
#         20090036 20160077
#20090036        0        4
#20160077        4        0

special_dist(x, "jaccard")
#          20090036  20160077
#20090036 0.0000000 0.5714286
#20160077 0.5714286 0.0000000
```